# Select most frequent elements by a variable

Tags: r

If I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)
ans=c(1,1,3,3,3,4,3,1,4)
d=cbind(id,ans)
```

How can I select the most frequent answer per ID?

I would like to return a data frame that looks like this:

```
id=c(1,2,3)
ans=c(1,3,4)
d.out=cbind(id,ans)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a 2-way table, and then find the max count in each row:

```
tab <- table(id, ans)
data.frame(id=rownames(tab), ans=colnames(tab)[max.col(tab)])
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
res <- sapply(split(ans, id), function(x) names(sort(table(x),decreasing=TRUE)[1]))
data.frame(id = names(res), ans = res)
  id ans
1  1   1
2  2   3
3  3   4
```